# Why is Programming Puzzles & Code Golf page on SE still in beta?

Tags: discussion

If we look at the [Area 51 page for  Programming Puzzles & Code Golf on SE](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4570/code-golf-programming-puzzles)  it looks that has all it takes to graduate:

[image]

Then why is  Programming Puzzles & Code Golf page on SE still in beta ?

Comment: might be relevant: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/does-this-site-have-a-chance-of-succeeding/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm guessing it's *probably* because we only have 3 users with 10k rep or more. And only 10ks can vote to delete (on non-beta sites). So since it takes 3 votes to delete a post, that means that those users **all** have to vote to delete the same post for it to be deleted.

(And we don't even have any 20k users!)

Oh, and PPCG is... *special*. The answer ratio is pretty moot since code golf questions get tons of answers naturally anyway, and % answered is irrelevant for the same reason. The answer to "when will we get out of beta" is usually "when you're ready," and I don't think we're ready yet.

Comment: The situation has changed now there are more than a dozen with over 10k but the site is still beta

Comment: @EduardFlorinescu And it's changed again! Now we've graduated! :-)

Answer (score 5):

Apparently the site is qualifying now something failed to trigger, see:
[Why is Code Golf & Programming Puzzles still in beta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274340/why-code-golf-programming-puzzles-is-still-in-beta/274457#274457)

[Grace Note](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/146126) in a [comment to an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274340/why-code-golf-programming-puzzles-is-still-in-beta#comment891571_274343):

> Music and Japanese were in the loop before we set the new criteria.
>   Aviation hit "eligibility" on October 19th. All 3 had delayed
>   graduations, the former because of the whole design thing and the
>   latter due to the pileup of graduations from implementing design
>   independent. **We just ran Code Golf through the eligibility check
>   though, and it passed, and probably should've passed a while ago. So
>   we're looking into why it hasn't been flagged yet.**

(Emphasis mine)